Redesign Ludo with more than 4 players
Is it possible to design a Ludo game with more than 4 players?  If we want a 5/6/7/8 players' game does it require the board to be pentagon/hexagon/septagon/octagon respectively?

Sure anything is possible but it would have an impact on the gameplay.

Actually, it will not effect so much the game play, players will just have to wait longer between their turns and more players to eat / get eaten by each other.

@Cohensius Games will also take longer as well not only due to what you mention but from the board being larger as well.

@JoeW, This can be easily adjust: reduce the number of steps per section and/or the number of meeples per player.

Yes, it is possible.  For example, see this video by Ludo king from 2021

